# Three.js Scene Violently Shaking

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js, webgl

I am currently working on a project that involves working with very large and very small distances using three.js

I am having an issue on the smaller side of the scene, where the 'scene' will start violently shaking.

At first I assumed it was a problem with the Z-Buffer, so I have written a small snippet that changes the near and far properties of the camera every time a new area is entered. This helped with the issues of  'shimmering' I was having before, however the scene still moves dramatically at small distances.

One of the conditions under which this happens is as follows

```
camera.near = .0133333
camera.far = 12
positionToObjects = 6
```

this should mean that the z resolution is around : .0001, which I feel like should be good enough, but the shaking that occurs is MUCH more then this.

The Objects themselves range everywhere from -200000 - 200000  in the 'global' position, however the scenes themselves do not change position

The other thing that I was thinking that it could be is the camera controls I have been using which are (abbrviated) as follows

```
if(mouseIsDown == true){
    if(this.movementSpeed < this.maxSpeed){
        this.movementSpeed += this.acceleration
    }else{
        this.movementSpeed = this.maxSpeed
    }

}else{
    if(this.movementSpeed > this.minSpeed){
        this.movementSpeed = this.movementSpeed/this.deceleration
    }else{
        this.movementSpeed = this.minSpeed  
    }

}
```

where this.minSpeed = 0, and this.movementSpeed is used to move the camera like so:

```
var actualSpeed = delta * this.movementSpeed;
this.object.translateZ( -actualSpeed * forwardOrAuto );
this.object.translateX( actualSpeed * sideSpeed );
this.object.translateY( actualSpeed * upSpeed );
```

However, even when the camera is not moving (up to 8 decimal places) the scene is still violently shaking

Are there any reasons that I cannot think of that would make a scene do this?

Please let me know if there is any more information that I can/should provide, and thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: My guess is that it is rounding errors, since you are using so few significant digits for the "close" scene...

Comment: for the camera, even 10^-8 is not accurate enough?

Comment: Also, is there any way to add more significant digits?

Comment: I've tried setting this.movementSpeed = 0.000000000000000000000000 , and even this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest you use values for *near* and *far* which are not that small? (Specifically for near)

*Near* is used as the divider internally, so if you're using a small number (<1) you might lose precision and end with those violent movements, as the range of values you're moving around is way smaller than if you used larger near and far values.

That's why you'll find the default value for *near* is 0.1:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r55/src/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.js#L13

... although I personally always use 1 for near.

Also, an online example is always good when asking for help in visual matters :-)

Comment: Hey Sole, Thanks for the suggestion, its one I've started taking steps towards. Its kindof cool to see feel like I've reached the 'end' of the webGL universe. As far as visual examples I didn't post any because the example: http://cabbibo.com/uOS/ is more of a 'labyrinth' then anything else and its hard to 'find' the areas that shake the most. (If you're curious Universe of Sound --> Europe --> Britain --> hyperdub --> whatever) is one of the shakiest, but good luck finding that one :)

Comment: Haha! You're the guy behind uOS! :-D Funny! I find your Universe pretty enigmatic. This "reaching the end of the WebGL verse" sounds equally enigmatic, but I think if you stay within the limits of Float numbers you should be able to navigate it without shaking. Maybe.

Comment: always the answer is maybe! Thanks for the kind words about the universe though, its been WAYYY too much work, so hearing something good about it makes it feel like its worth it!